# UIWebView is not scrolling the content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that loads the url. When I select some drop down in the `UIwebView`, it reloads the content. After that its stops scrolling and if change orientation of the device then it's scrolling in both(Potrait and Landscape) orientation. What could be the issue?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        let url1 = "url";// Valid url
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url1)!
        let urlr:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(urlr)
    }
```

Comment: Show us your codes.

Comment: Put your codes in your question ( hard to read in comments )

Comment: which xcode version you are using?